# Condition on $n$ so that $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{L}^n$ is generated by global sections when $\mathcal{L}$ is ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent scheaf fixed.

By definition if $\mathcal{L}$ is an ample invertible scheaf, there exists an integer $n_0$ such that for every $n\geqslant n_0$ one has $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{L}^n$ is generated by its global sections.

My question is about this integer $n_0$. Yes, it depends on $\mathcal{L}$. But is there some criterion from the degre of $\mathcal{L}^n$?

To be more specific: $\mathcal{F}$ being fixed, is there an integer $N$ such that for every ample invertible scheaf $\mathcal{L}$, for all integer $n$ with $\deg(\mathcal{L}^n)\geqslant N$ one has $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{L}^n$ generated by global sections?

This question comes from the proof of proposition V.2.8 in Hartshorne where the generating by global sections of $\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{L}^n$ seems depend only of the degree of $\mathcal{L}^n$.

Comment: It would be enough that: if $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{L}^n$ is G.G.S. (generating by global sections) and $\deg(\mathcal{M}^k)\geqslant\deg(\mathcal{L}^n)$ then $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{M}^k$ is G.G.S.

Comment: I find another solution for V.2.8... so I guess that what I guess is false?